# Can I have chapters numbered while not having them appear in the table of contents automatically?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, titles, titletoc

I have a thesis file that has chapters, sections, etc.
In the document I make references to previous lemmas, etc.

I want to remove the automatic generation in the table of contents of the chapter titles.
The reason for this is that there appearance in the document needs to be different from their appearance in the table of contents.

I can use the command \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table Of Contents Chapter Title Style}
which appears in the Table of Contents correctly.
However it appears right after the chapter title which has the same format as the way it was typed in the command  \chapter{In Body Chapter Title}.

Is there a way to suppress the printing of the \chapter{In Body Chapter Title} from the table of contents without using the \chapter* command?

I don't want to mess up the references that are throughout the document nor the section numbering.

Thanks

Comment: Regarding: "The reason for this is that there appearance in the document needs to be different from their appearance in the table of contents.": So, do you really want to entirely remove the chapter from the table of contents or do you just want to display a different text in the table of contents than in the document? If the latter is the case, use `\chapter[text in the toc]{text in the document}`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can't believe I wasn't aware of that. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the optional argument to `\chapter` which specifies the title text to appear in the ToC.

```
\chapter[]{Title in document}
```

will result in no title text in the ToC.